# How to use calligraphy library in Android

Tags: android, calligraphy

I want use [Calligraphy library](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) in my project, but in my application is use this code for change **google map** language :

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
}
```

for use calligraphy i should use this code :

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
```

How can i use two `attachBaseContext` in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's pretty easy, just chain it:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    newBase = MyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase, "fa_IR");
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
```

Or you could extract a parent `BaseActivity` and apply Calligraphy to all your activities in one place. And override language only in the map activity. In that case it will look like your orginal code as each wrapper will be applied in a different class.